# Satirical journals for the arts and humanities

Tags: publications, journals, literature, humanities

It was very easy to find scientific journals that allow satirical articles to be published. The top Google result for "satirical journals" was Wikipedia's list of them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parody_science

> ## Parody science
>
> **Parody science**, sometimes called **spoof science**, is the act of mocking science in a satirical way.
>
> ...
>
> [Proceedings of the Natural Institute of Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proceedings_of_the_Natural_Institute_of_Science) - Online-only journal that publishes both satirical and real articles in a scientific journal format.

But I have had no luck finding satirical journals or journals that will publish satire for the humanities.

How can I find popular journals (or functionally equivalent) that exist in the humanities, literatures, languages, cultures, arts, etc., that will similarly publish satirical articles?

Comment: The old (?) Journal of Irreproducible Results had a range of articles on different areas, some in the humanities. But it has been 40+ years since I read it. Seems to still exist but I have no info on the current types of articles.

Comment: You asked this question before: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/177936/64.  It was closed as a shopping question.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche it is not a shopping question

Comment: But it is. Have you checked the definition of a shopping question? https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-shopping

Comment: @Jeroen yes and it doesn't describe this question. In fact it even explicitly states my question to not be one: "Note that questions about how to make such a choice in general – that do not involve naming any of the above – are not considered shopping questions"